# Importing several icons at once using react-icons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, react-icons

I'm trying to import multiple icons from the [same pack at once](https://github.com/gorangajic/react-icons), in this case, font-awesome like this:

```
import {FaPencilSquare,FaHome} from 'react-icons/fa'
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-icons/fa/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected { (1:7)

> 1 | export Fa500px from './500px';
    |        ^
  2 | export FaAdjust from './adjust';
  3 | export FaAdn from './adn';
  4 | export FaAlignCenter from './align-center';
```

If I import icons separately I don't get any errors,
any ideas what it could be?

Comment: There is an [issue](https://github.com/gorangajic/react-icons/issues/99) that might be related to your question. I just saw it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @bennygenel it seems like there is an open issue with that a workaround is to add the **lib folder** to your import like this:

```
import {FaHome,FaPencilSquare} from 'react-icons/lib/fa'
```